# What is the probability of single round bubble sort getting the right order

Tags: probability, sorting

Given a  permutation of {1,2,...,n}, what is the probability of a single round bubble sort getting the right order?

For example:

a). 5,1,2,3,4 -> 1,5,2,3,4 -> 1,2,5,3,4 -> 1,2,3,5,4 -> 1,2,3,4,5. After the first round, the order is right;

b). 1,2,5,4,3 -> 1,2,4,5,3 -> 1,2,4,3,5, After the first round, the order is still not right.

I guess the equivalent condition is that `a least n-1 numbers are in the right order.` If it is right, how to calculated the probability?

If we fix the four elements with right and put the left one anywhere, there will be a lot of duplicates. e.g.

fix 1,2,3,4 and put 5: 1,2,3,(5),4 is duplicate with fix 1,2,3,5 and put 4: 1,2,3,5,(4).

Comment: 2,1,4,3 doesn't have three numbers in the right order

Comment: @Empy2 OK, then my conjecture  is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n-1$ comparisons, so $2^{n-1}$ possible sequences of actions - swap or don't swap.  To find the permutations, start with 1,2,3,4,5 and undo a sequence.
For example, if $n=5$, there are $2^4=16$ out of $5!=120$ that end after one round of bubble sort.
For one of them, you do Swap,Leave,Swap,Swap.  That is
A: Swap places 1,2;
B: Leave places 2,3;
C: Swap places 3,4;
D: Swap places 4,5, end with 1,2,3,4,5.
To find out the starting point for that one, undo the sequence
D: UnSwap places 4,5, end with 1,2,3,5,4
C: Unswap places 3,4, end with 1,2,5,3,4
B Leave 2,3 alone
A: Unswap places 1,2, end with 2,1,5,3,4

Comment: sorry, don't get your point, could say more detail and what's the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the answer given by @Empy2, there are $n!$ possible permutations of n numbers. We want only permutations that end up in a sorted array after a single pass. A single pass runs $n-1$ operations that could be encoded as 0 (no swap) or 1 (swap). In total there are $2^{n-1}$ possible swap ombinations for the last pass of the buble sort. So to get the probability you just divide it by the total number of permutations:
$$
p=\frac {2^{n-1}} {n!}
$$
In case of 5 item list it's $2^4/5!=0.1(3)$